# Catch-22 in serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I am writing a program which creates objects, referenced in an ArrayList which starts as an empty ArrayList.  The user populates it at runtime based on information that they provide.

I am attempting to serialize the ArrayList and the classes that build its objects using the standard

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Foo.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
    os.writeObject(barList);
    os.close();

    }  catch(IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
```

When the program runs the first time, the file (foo.ser) has not been created yet, so to attempt to use the corresponding FileInputStream method to retrieve state will, to the best of my knowledge, cause a file not found exception.

I considered using an if statement checking for foo.ser, and only implementing the FileInputStream if it was found, but the format for the file check seems to be an absolute path.  That doesn't seem to be the candidate for a robust solution.  How do you get the ball rolling on Serialization if your program starts off with no object state and no Foo.ser?

Comment: Why not just catch the `FileNotFoundException` and proceed with an empty array list?

Comment: Sorry, every example I found had the program terminating in that event, I didn't know I could just basically ignore it!  Great news, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I considered using an if statement checking for `foo.ser`, and only implementing the `FileInputStream` if it was found, but the format for the file check seems to be an absolute path.

That is incorrect.  You can check for the existence of a file using either a relative or absolute path.

But as NPE points out it is simpler to just attempt to open and read the file, and catch the exceptions that can happen if that fails.  (The file could be missing, you might not have read permission, or the file could exist but deserialization could fail.)